# Listview adapter's button can not be clicked

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using listview's adapter, my code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="position1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn_like"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Button"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_translate_blue"
        android:clickable="true" //Add this is to allow this to get focus, but the button can not be clicked.
        >
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

When i remove android:clickable="true", the button can be clicked, but the RelativeLayout can not focused.
  How to achieve a similar effect as Google Plus?

**UPDATE**
Now only RelativeLayout can be clicked.
I mean how to make the Button also can be clicked?
NOT click them two at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `android:focusable` and `android:focusableInTouchMode` to `false` to your button:

```
<Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn_like"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Button"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            />
```

**UPDATE**
You need to set your `Button` `android:focusable` as `false` and also the `RelativeLayout`. Plus, you need to have a `selector` for your both `Button` and `RelativeLayout`
Here:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_like"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"/>
```

And Here:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_translate_blue"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_ll"
        android:focusable="false" >
```

And here is the important thing, in those `selector`s, at the `android:state_pressed`, you need to add more the `android:state_focused`, this way, when the item click, the `Button` and `RelativeLayout` can NOT get `focusable`, so it will NOT trigger this state:

selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_focused="true"></item>
</selector>
```

selector_ll.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.No use ah..., I want both the Button and the RelativeLayout can be clicked.

Comment: @tenpage Look like your `LinearLayout` is overlapping your `RelativeLayout`, so you can NOT touch the `RelativeLayout`, pass the `onClick` event from your `LinearLayout` down to your `RelativeLayout`. See my update. Cheers!

Comment: @tenpage Well, I just implemented myself and I saw your problem, still figure out how this problem occurs. Cheers!

Comment: @tenpage, I figure out the way to do it, check my answer, I have updated again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding android:focusable="true" or android:focusableInTouchMode="true" to your relativelayout?